# delete all cache file in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I want to delete all file from /tmp/cache. My code spinet is below:

```
\Cake\Cache\Cache::delete();
```

but it gives the error below:
-Error: Too few arguments to function Cake\Cache\Cache::delete(), 0 passed in G:\xamp727\htdocs\bootique_api\src\Controller\PagesController.php on line 94 and at least 1 expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete all use clearAll() method. [method doc](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Cache.Cache.html#_clearAll)